# JS - how to count (filtered) words as you iterate through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, filtering

Learning JavaScript, currently at iterators doing a project to 'lint' an array that has a text story. Linting referring to the process of editing/filtering out words or grammar from some form of writing.

My issue - currently I can get it to .filter overusedWords, but I want to save the amount of times a word has been used and return that amount like: ("You used ${overusedWords} X times"). However it only prints the word I'm filtering however many times it appears.

I've tried defining word counters inside / outside this iterator loop. Right now I'm trying to rewrite that section as 'if (overused.filter(word => { === 'example'}) type

The project is to get used to .(iterator) methods so solutions should revolve around using it. Hopefully you can help me figure this out and better learn :)

```
let word1 = 0;
let word2 = 0;
let word3 = 0;

const countOverUsed = betterWords.filter((word, word1, word2, word3) => {

  if (word === 'really') {
    word1 = word1 + 1;
    return word1;
  } else if (word === 'very') {
    word2 = word2 + 1;
    return word2;
  } else if (word === 'basically') {
    word3 = word3 + 1;
    return word3;

  }
});

console.log(countOverUsed);
```

Whole project

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

const storyWords = story.split(' ');
console.log(storyWords.length);

const betterWords = storyWords.filter(function(element) {
  if (unnecessaryWords.includes(element)) {
    console.log(element)
  } else {
    return element;
  }
});


let word1 = 0;
let word2 = 0;
let word3 = 0;

const countOverUsed = betterWords.filter((word, word1, word2, word3) => {

  if (word === 'really') {
    word1 = word1 + 1;
    return word1;
  } else if (word === 'very') {
    word2 = word2 + 1;
    return word2;
  } else if (word === 'basically') {
    word3 = word3 + 1;
    return word3;

  }
});

console.log(countOverUsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array matching the filter criteria inside the function. Depending on a boolean return value it adds the current element to the return value or not.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].filter((value) => {
  return value % 2
}); // returns: [1, 3, 5]
```

If you want to iterate through every element of an array use a any kind of loop or [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

You can use several methods to search for the words inside the text.

Here is an example with [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
let overusedWordsCount = {};
overusedWords.forEach((word) => {
  overusedWordsCount[word] = 0;
  for (let position = 0;story.indexOf(word, position) > -1; overusedWordsCount[word]++) {
    position = story.indexOf(word, position) + word.length;
  }
});
Object.entries(overusedWordsCount).forEach(([ word, value ]) => {
  console.log(`You used ${word} ${value} time${value == 1 ? '' : 's'}.`);
});
```